# harmony book recommendations

Tags: theory, harmony

I'm studying Gradus ad Parnassum, and love its didactic over theoretical manner.

Are there similar books to teach how to write for more instruments?

I've seen various books recommended: Tchaikovsky's, Schoenberg's, Rimsky-Korsakov's book on harmony etc

are they the same in theory or do they have fundamental differences?

Comment: Book recommendations are off topic.

Comment: It seems, that [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22998/where-to-start-with-orchestration) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Big picture: At the earliest stages, learning to write means learning to understand what others have written, which means analyzing... which means you're looking for a beginner (or intermediate?) music theory textbook. There are several major ones. There are also textbooks on orchestration (not "which chords," but which instruments to use when, and how to make sure you're not asking them to do what they can't).

Comment: Did you mean specifically _dialog_ source rather than didactic? The thing about Fux is the book is a _dialog_ between a teacher and a student.